# XSD Regular expression to match first 4 characters

Tags: xsd, xsd-validation

XSD Regular expression to match first 4 characters and it should not match any other chars for group. I have tried `[A]{4}[^A]*`, but the rest values are been taken by group.

Comment: I have tried this [A]{4}[^A]*, but the rest values are been taken by group

Comment: Don't add information in the comments, edit the question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.